# Xamarin iOS UIPageViewController SetViewControllers see page between

Tags: ios, xamarin, uipageviewcontroller

I'm creating a project with an UIPageViewController and tabs just above it.

I want to navigate with Tabs, so I know that I can use `SetViewControllers(controller, ...)` to jump to another tabs.

But if a have 3 controllers (A, B, C) then I jump from A to C, how can I make an animation which also show B before jumping to C ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to C after you jumping from A to B in the callback Event_handler of the method `SetViewControllers`.Refer the following code.

```
pageViewController = new UIPageViewController(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal,UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Max);

//...
pageViewController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { B }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, (bool finished) =>
  {    
      pageViewController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { C }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true,null);
  });
```